# MongoDB (Mongoose) database query question

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get all the documents from a collection that have a variable amount of failed exams.

My collection is the following:
[image: Student db in mongoDB]

I have to retrieve all student that have for example 3 scores lower than 10.

The query I am currently running is the following:

```
Student.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                name: 1,
                students: {
                    count: {
                        $size: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$results",
                                as: "result",
                                cond: {$lt: ["$$result.score", 10]}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

How would I check if the count is $gte then for example 3?

My current output:
[image: Query output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost 100% done already!   Just add

```
{$match: {"students.count": {$gte: 3}}
```

as a stage in the pipeline after `$project`.